# React native inline if statments

Tags: javascript, react-native

Hello I am stuck on this issue where I can't figure out how to do inline if else statment in react native.

```
        {currentSlideIndex == 0 ? (
        <>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView style={{flex:1}} behavior='position'>
        

        <BlurView intensity={20} tint="light" >
              <Text style={styles.label}>Name</Text>
        <TextInput  
            value={name}
            onChangeText={onNameChange}
            style={styles.input}
        />
        </BlurView>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        </>
      ):(
        <>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView style={{flex:1}} behavior='position'>
        

        <BlurView intensity={20} tint="light" >
              <Text style={styles.label}>Surname</Text>
        <TextInput  
            value={name}
            onChangeText={onNameChange}
            style={styles.input}
        />
        </BlurView>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        </>
        
      )}
```

I want it to make it so that I have currentslideIndex == 0 , currentslideIndex == 1 ,currentslideIndex == 2.

Comment: To me this looks like an interesting problem, and I’m gonna suggest something being creative here. Not really sure if its the best approach. So may be you can create a map of your functional components like const myMap = { 1: (name) => <YourComponent1 name={name} />, 2 : (name) => <YourComponent2 name={name} />, … } and then you can use it to render like this return (myMap[currentSlideIndex](name))

Comment: nested ternaries are fun!

Comment: Hello, I did that and it worked perfectly making a map function to run my 3 if statements but the issue I was having was when you click on the textinput and type 1 letter the keyboard would go down and when its in the overall return() that issue is solved so I was wondering if there is a option of inline if else statements.

Comment: Another approach i can think of is  { index === 1 &&(<YourComponent>)} {index ===2 && (<YourComponent2>} and so on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code below:

```
    {
        currentSlideIndex == 0 ? (
            <>
                {/* code for slide 0 */}
            </>
        ) : (currentSlideIndex == 1 ? (
            <>
                {/* code for slide 1 */}
            </>
        ) : (
                <>
                    {/* code for slide 2 */}
                </>
            )
        )
    }
```

Comment: there is an extra parenthesis before your second ternary condition that breaks this code

Answer (score 0):

you want something like:

```js
{currentSlideIndex === 0 ? 
    (...) :
 currentSlideIndex === 1 ?
    (...) : //currentSlideIndex === 2
    (...)
}
```

you can actually nest ternaries so that there are multiple if/else if conditions!

OR:

you can have a variable before the return of your render function i.e.

```
let keyboardAvoidingView;
if (currentSlideIndex === 0) {
    keyboardAvoidingView = ...
}
else if (currentSlideIndex === 1) {
    keyboardAvoidingView = ...
}
else {
    keyboardAvoidingView = ...
}
```

then in render, just render your variable:

```
{keyboardAvoidingView}
```

Answer (score 0):

if-else statements don't work inside JSX. This is because JSX is just syntactic sugar for function calls and object construction.

So in Jsx it actually becomes something like

```js
render(if (true) return 0)
// This doesn't work because you can't put conditional inside function calls
```

But if you were mapping inside jsx using `{ x.map(x => { if (true) return <Component //>)}` would work. For Conditionals you can only use ternary.

But You can achieve what you are saying by using Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)

```js
render() {
    return (   
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {(() => {
              if (this.state == 'news'){
                  return (
                      <Text>data</Text>
                  )
              }
              
              return null;
            })()}
        </View>
    )
}
```